# Netbeans: Error installing IMlet....Emulator Error

Tags: java, netbeans, java-me, emulation

Windows 8.1
Java ME SDK 8
Netbeans 8

Since downloading Netbeans a few days ago I've been having persistent problems. It's very slow and the the emulator starts up less than half the time. MosT of the time

I get An error once the emulator opens and it's about the begin running the program. It says:

Error Installing IMlet: See Device Log for Details.  (see attachment)

The FATAL error message in the log is as follows:

[03:55:09.401]  FATAL - lkit.ui.actions.AmsExecInstall - Unknown error: invalid url: file:///C:/Users/Kevins Home/Desktop/GPIOLEDTest/dist/GPIOLEDTest.jad    (see attachment)

This problem also occurs on my girlfriends MAC using the same code + setup.

There's very little online material that seems to be relevant.

Would love to figure out what's wrong so I can finish this course: Develop Java Embedded Applications with a Raspberry Pi

[image]

The device Log:

[image]

I've tried moving the project to a path without spaces, alsl, but i still get the same error:

[04:40:10.688]  FATAL - lkit.ui.actions.AmsExecInstall - Unknown error: invalid url: file:///C:/Users/Public/GPIOLEDTest/dist/GPIOLEDTest.jad

Thanks in advance

Comment: try to move project where there is no space in file path

Comment: Tried it already. No luck.

Answer (score 0):

Reinstall. There are step by step instructions in this video, which is part of the course you are taking: http://youtu.be/tnC-nEwkdIg

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure exactly why it fixed the problem, but when I connected my external device ( a raspberry pi) to my laptop via an ethernet cable instead of doing it wirelessly the problem seemed to go away. My SSH must have been too weak to consistently run the emulator. Once it had a strong SSH through the ehternet cable the problem went away. If anyone knows more about exactly why this happened it be happy to hear..

Answer (score -1):

download sdk 3.4 instead of sdk 8

Comment: please could you explain why?